# If statement in python not printing

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I am working on an assignment for school, and this program is SUPER easy, but my if statement isn't working properly. Does anybody know why? Here is the code:

```
letter = input("Name one of the most common letters in wheel of fortune puzzles: ")

if letter == "r":
    print(letter, "is one of the most common letters!")
if letter == "s":
    print(letter, "is one of the most common letters!")
if letter == "t":
    print(letter, "is one of the most common letters!")
if letter == "l":
    print(letter, "is one of the most common letters!")
if letter == "n":
    print(letter, "is one of the most common letters!")
if letter == "e":
    print(letter, "is one of the most common letters!")

else:
    print("Incorrect!")
    letter = input("Name one of the most common letters in wheel of fortune puzzles: ")


input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit:")
```

Output is:

```
Name one of the most common letters in wheel of fortune puzzles: j
Incorrect!
Name one of the most common letters in wheel of fortune puzzles: r


Press the enter key to exit:
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. What does "not working" mean? Provide sample input and output. Also, your `else` is only connected to the very last `if`, so if the letter isn't "e" you are guaranteed to see `"Incorrect!"`. Use `elif ... :` instead.

Comment: Okay, sorry. The output is

Comment: i'll just edit my original

Answer (score 5):

I would write something like this:

```
# Assumes Python 3
# Python 2: Use `raw_input` instead of input

common_letters = 'rstlne'
prompt = "Name one of the most common letters in wheel of fortune puzzles: "

while True:
    letter = input(prompt).strip()
    if letter in common_letters:
        print(letter, "is one of the most common letters!")
        break
    else:
        print("Incorrect!")
        answer = input('Type "end" to exit: ')
        if answer.strip() == 'end':
            break
```

There are a few thing I changed:

1. Instead of that many `if` statements I used `if letter in common_letters:`. This allows you to just add ore remove another letter to/from `common_letters`.
2. I use `input(prompt).strip()`to strip of extra white space.
3. I use a `while True` loop to repeat the question over and over again if no common letter was entered. The `break` terminates this loop, i.e. the progam is finished.

Comment: thank you! this worked. the others assumed i was running python2, but i am using python3.

Comment: now how would i make it end the loop, and also on the first time it asks "Name one of the most common letters in wheel of fortune puzzles: " it doesn't print "Incorrect!", how would i make it do that?

Comment: @E.Ingraham Did you run the program? It asks this question and exits when th letter is common. Otherwise it prints "Incorrect!" and keeps asking.

Comment: I copied it down incorrectly, sorry! it works now. thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Added another question asking to user if  he/sh wants to end the program.

Comment: @E.Ingraham You can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give input as `"r"` or simple use `raw_input()`.raw_input accepts `string` which is not the case with `input`=`eval(raw_input(prompt)).`So it will search for `r` variable unless you say `"r"` which tells it that it is a string.

Comment: I'm sorry....I'm really new to this stuff, can you explain that in more "dumbed down" terms? My B

Comment: like this?  'letter = input("Name one of the most common letters in wheel of fortune puzzles: ")

if letter == r:
    print(letter, "is one of the most common letters!")
elif letter == s:
    print(letter, "is one of the most common letters!")' etc.....

Comment: `letter = input("Name one of the most common letters in wheel of fortune puzzles: ")

if letter == r:
    print(letter, "is one of the most common letters!")
elif letter == s:
    print(letter, "is one of the most common letters!")`

Comment: okay, how would i make it let me just give `r`? it's a requirement for the assignment.

Comment: i tried that, didn't make a difference. `raw_input()` function wasn't colored like functions usually are as well.

Comment: @E.Ingraham leave your first `if` and change all the rest to `elif` and keep `else` at last

Comment: I am running python 3.1.1, that was the problem, @MikeMuller helped me. thank you!

Comment: @E.Ingraham you can use your own program...you just need to change `if` to `elif` leaving the first `if` intact

Comment: no error, just didn't print the `(letter, "is one of the most common letters!")` when you input the correct letter

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following changes inyour code.

1. From 2nd `if` condition change it to `elif` because if you enter for example 's' then it will go in the 2nd `if` condition and also the `else` part will run.
2. change `input`  to     `raw_input` example change

`letter = input("Name one of the most common letters in wheel of fortune puzzles: ")` to

`letter = raw_input("Name one of the most common letters in wheel of fortune puzzles: ")`

Comment: I did your step 1, but raw_input gave me an error `raw_input is not defined`

Comment: `raw_input` should work by default. It is similar to `input`, only difference lies is that you need not enter anything with `''` for input

Comment: It is defined and useful in Python 2, but the question is apparently about Python 3.

Comment: Ok. Did not have a look at the Python 3 tag in the question

Answer (score 0):

```
#considering you enter 'j' and 'r' here's the path your code takes

letter = input("Name one of the most common letters in wheel of fortune puzzles: ")  
# letter now = 'j'

if letter == "r": # letter don't equal 'r', don't do next line
    print(letter, "is one of the most common letters!")
if letter == "s": # letter don't equal 's', don't do next line
    print(letter, "is one of the most common letters!")
if letter == "t": # letter don't equal 't', don't do next line
    print(letter, "is one of the most common letters!")
if letter == "l": # letter don't equal 'l', don't do next line
    print(letter, "is one of the most common letters!")
if letter == "n": # letter don't equal 'n', don't do next line
    print(letter, "is one of the most common letters!")
if letter == "e": # letter don't equal 'e', don't do next line
    print(letter, "is one of the most common letters!")

else: # because last if was false (letter don't equal 'e') do next line.
    print("Incorrect!") #  output : Incorrect!
# next line is not consider inside else. should be included within {} if desired
    letter = input("Name one of the most common letters in wheel of fortune puzzles: ") 
# letter now equals 'r'

#nothing to do with it


input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit:") 
# showing Press the enter key to exit: and waiting.
```

This would work as I think you want.

```
letter = raw_input("Name one of the most common letters in wheel of fortune puzzles: ")

if letter == "r":
    print(letter, "is one of the most common letters!")
elif letter == "s":
    print(letter, "is one of the most common letters!")
elif letter == "t":
    print(letter, "is one of the most common letters!")
elif letter == "l":
    print(letter, "is one of the most common letters!")
elif letter == "n":
    print(letter, "is one of the most common letters!")
elif letter == "e":
    print(letter, "is one of the most common letters!")
else:
    print("Incorrect!")

raw_input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit:")
```

Comment: Please test your code before posting it. Comments in Python start with `#`.